# Implement quicksort algorithm in two ways but only one accepted?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I have implemented quicksort algorithm in 2 ways.

The **quick_sort** function is the same :

```
void quick_sort(int *a, int left, int right) {
    if (left < right) {
        int mid = partition(a, left, right);
        quick_sort(a, left, mid - 1);
        quick_sort(a, mid + 1, right);
}
```

The **partition** function is different in two implementation :

The first way based on "Algorithm" book of Robert Sedgewick :

```
int random = rand() % (right - left + 1) + left;
exchange(&a[left], &a[random]);

int i = left;
int j = right + 1;
int pivot = a[left];

while (1) {
    while (a[++i] < pivot)
        if (i == right) break;
    while (a[--j] > pivot)
        if (j == left) break;

    if (i >= j) break;

    exchange(&a[i], &a[j]);
}

exchange(&a[left], &a[j]);

return j;
```

The second way based on "Introduction to algorithm" book, this way is way much easier to understand than the first way :

```
int random = rand() % (right - left + 1) + left;
exchange(&a[right], &a[random]);

int pivot = a[right];
int j = left - 1;

int i;
for (i = left; i < right; i++) {
    if (a[i] <= pivot) {
        j++;
        exchange(&a[j], &a[i]);
    }
}

exchange(&a[j + 1], &a[right]);

return j + 1;
```

I have submitted two implementation on Online Judge Site : [TSORT](http://www.spoj.com/problems/TSORT/), but only the first implementation was accepted, the second one was Time Limit Exceed. There are slight differences, but i can't find the one that cause the gap of performance, can someone find and then explain this ?

Comment: did you try putting some printf's/cout's inside of your non-working partition function to try to figure out why it's failing?

Comment: First try it with deterministic values instead of `rand`.

Comment: @LouisRicci I don't think OP is saying it is failing. It just that one has a better performance than the other by the online judge.

Comment: It's pretty obvious that the first implementation is more efficient, as it does far fewer swaps than the second one.

Comment: @VioletaMarin Yes it does, but the number of swaps do not make a significant performance here since two partition have complexity of O(N). It turns out the problem is when the array filled with equal elements, the partition position is always at the end of array, which cause quadratic time

Answer (score 3):

Your first one is the Hoare partition scheme, while the second one is the Lomuto partitioning scheme. According to multiple sources, Lomuto's variant should not be used in practice, its only advantage being pedagogical, because it is easier to understand.

Some such sources:

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

   > Hoare scheme is more efficient than Lomuto's partition scheme because it does **three times fewer swaps on average** and creates efficient partitions even when all values are equal.
2. https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11458/quicksort-partitioning-hoare-vs-lomuto

   > Lomuto's method is simple and easier to implement, but **should not be used for implementing a library sorting method**.